# Exercise package => tex capacity limit

Tags: exercises, capacity

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,openany,french]{book}
\usepackage{float}  % figure wont float anymore
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings,calc}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[lastexercise,answerdelayed]{exercise}



\begin{document}

\begin{Exercise}[label={}, difficulty={1}]
Prove whatever.
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
\tkzInit[xmin=-4,xmax=9,ymin=-3,ymax=9]
\tkzClip
\tkzDefPoint(2,3){A}
\tkzDefPoint[shift={(2,3)}](31:8){B}
\tkzDefPoint[shift={(2,3)}](158:8){C}
\tkzDrawSegments[color=red,line width=1pt](A,B A,C)
\tkzProtractor[scale=1.25,with=full,return](A,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}\label{uisf}
\end{figure}
\end{Answer}















\part{Solutions}
\shipoutAnswer

\end{document}
```

This code compiles but if you copy paste the exercise hundreds of times, tex capacity will be reached. The problem seems to be the `answerdelayed` option: tex doesn't have enough capacity to store the answers and print them at the end. How to solve this?

Comment: Your MWE is not executable.  My first guess is to avoid figure [H] and use \captionof{figure}{...} (caption package) instead.  I know that there are only about 20 free inserts for floats, but not if figure [H] uses one.  My second suggestion is to put the tikzpicture in a savebox if you intend to use it more than once.

Comment: please make a test file that shows the error, and also show the exact error that you get, copied from the log to a code block so line endings reserved.

Comment: it doesn't really make sense to have a float in an answer, so I would mark this up just as a tikzpicture, not mark it as a float then use `[H]` to say it's not really a float.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I need to number the figures and ref them.